# Why would angle grinder cutting wheels of the same diameter have different thickness?

Tags: powertools, metal-cutting

Cutting wheels for the same diameter angle grinder can have different thickness. For example, 125 millimeters wheels can be 0,8 or 1,0 or 1,2 or 2,5 or 3,0 millimeters thick. I've tried several variations - looks like the thinner the wheel the faster it cuts because the smaller is the contact surface.

What's the reason for having so many thickness varieties of cutting wheels of the same diameter?

Comment: Avoid using an angle grinder to cut, as it is not a recommended use and quite dangerous.  (They are called angle "grinders" for a reason -- they're intended to grind, not cut.)  Furthermore, if your grinder doesn't have a shield (some don't,) I wouldn't use it it all.  Whenever possible, use metal shears, a reciprocating saw, a portable bandsaw, or other tool.

Comment: @Michael: Where I live an angle grinder is used to perform almost all metal cutting works whenever possible. Also I've never seen any statement that cutting is not a recommended use.

Comment: Though often used for cutting, it is, unfortunately, a very unsafe practice.  If the material pinches the disc, it will cause the grinder to kick (you get away with it 99.9% of the time, but the .1% can be very dangerous) or shatter the cutting disc, either of which can easily result in a trip to the emergency room or worse.  Reconstructive surgery, permanent loss of vision, etc.  They are probably the most unwieldy, erratic, and dangerous tool that you can buy at a HI store.  Similar injuries can happen with any tool, of course, but it usually requires a severe case of operator error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [Norton Catalog](http://www.nortonindustrial.com/uploadedFiles/SGindnortonabrasives/Documents/Catalog_PDFs/NortonCatalog-Cut-offWheels.pdf):

> .035, .040, .045, .060 Where fast cutting and low kerf loss are
> desired
>
> .090, .125 For tough cutting and notching applications where
> stability is important

I would also expect that longevity plays into the equation for industrial applications (not something a DIY-er needs to care about)